# Kafka cluster migration over clouds, how to ensure consumers consume from right offsets when offsets are managed by us?

Tags: apache-kafka

For migration of Kafka clusters from AWS to AZURE, the challenge is that we are using our custom offsets management for consumers. If I replicate the ZK nodes with offsets, the Kafka Mirror will change those offsets. Is there any way to ensure the offsets are same so that migration can be smooth?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be your custom management. Without more details on this, it's hard to give suggestions.

The problem I see with trying to copy offsets at all is that you consume from cluster A, topic T offset 1000. You copy this to a brand new cluster B, you now have topic T, **offset 0**. Having consumers starting at offset 1000 will just fail  in this scenario, or if at least 1000 messages were mirrored, then you're effectively skipping that data.

---

With newer versions of Kafka (post 0.10), MirrorMaker uses the the `__consumer_offsets` topic, not Zookeeper since it's built on newer Java clients.

As for replication tools, [uber/uReplicator](https://github.com/uber/uReplicator) uses ZooKeeper for offsets.

There are other tools that manage offsets differently, such as [Comcast/MirrorTool](https://github.com/Comcast/MirrorTool-for-Kafka-Connect/pull/10) or [salesforce/mirus](https://github.com/salesforce/mirus) via the Kafka Connect Framework.

---

And the enterprise supported tool would be Confluent Replicator, which has unique ways of handling cluster failover and migrations.